# Convert React-Spring Example to Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-spring

Tried copying [this example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/j0y0vpz59), but I'm using gatsby & styled components; So I'm trying to convert the plain css file to styled-components. However, the cards aren't moving or reacting at all when I click or drag, did I do something horribly wrong?

This file is pretty much just copy/paste:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSprings, animated, interpolate } from "react-spring";
import { useGesture } from "react-use-gesture";

const cards = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f5/RWS_Tarot_08_Strength.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/RWS_Tarot_16_Tower.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/RWS_Tarot_07_Chariot.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/RWS_Tarot_06_Lovers.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/RWS_Tarot_02_High_Priestess.jpg/690px-RWS_Tarot_02_High_Priestess.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/de/RWS_Tarot_01_Magician.jpg"
];

// These two are just helpers, they curate spring data, values that are later being interpolated into css
const to = i => ({
  x: 0,
  y: i * -4,
  scale: 1,
  rot: -10 + Math.random() * 20,
  delay: i * 100
});
const from = i => ({ x: 0, rot: 0, scale: 1.5, y: -1000 });
// This is being used down there in the view, it interpolates rotation and scale into a css transform
const trans = (r, s) =>
  `perspective(1500px) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(${r /
    10}deg) rotateZ(${r}deg) scale(${s})`;

function Deck() {
  const [gone] = useState(() => new Set()); // The set flags all the cards that are flicked out
  const [props, set] = useSprings(cards.length, i => ({
    ...to(i),
    from: from(i)
  })); // Create a bunch of springs using the helpers above
  // Create a gesture, we're interested in down-state, delta (current-pos - click-pos), direction and velocity
  const bind = useGesture(
    ({
      args: [index],
      down,
      delta: [xDelta],
      distance,
      direction: [xDir],
      velocity
    }) => {
      const trigger = velocity > 0.2; // If you flick hard enough it should trigger the card to fly out
      const dir = xDir < 0 ? -1 : 1; // Direction should either point left or right
      if (!down && trigger) gone.add(index); // If button/finger's up and trigger velocity is reached, we flag the card ready to fly out
      set(i => {
        if (index !== i) return; // We're only interested in changing spring-data for the current spring
        const isGone = gone.has(index);
        const x = isGone ? (200 + window.innerWidth) * dir : down ? xDelta : 0; // When a card is gone it flys out left or right, otherwise goes back to zero
        const rot = xDelta / 100 + (isGone ? dir * 10 * velocity : 0); // How much the card tilts, flicking it harder makes it rotate faster
        const scale = down ? 1.1 : 1; // Active cards lift up a bit
        return {
          x,
          rot,
          scale,
          delay: undefined,
          config: { friction: 50, tension: down ? 800 : isGone ? 200 : 500 }
        };
      });
      if (!down && gone.size === cards.length)
        setTimeout(() => gone.clear() || set(i => to(i)), 600);
    }
  );
  // Now we're just mapping the animated values to our view, that's it. Btw, this component only renders once. :-)
  return props.map(({ x, y, rot, scale }, i) => (
    <animated.div
      key={i}
      style={{
        transform: interpolate([x, y], (x, y) => `translate3d(${x}px,${y}px,0)`)
      }}
    >
      {/* This is the card itself, we're binding our gesture to it (and inject its index so we know which is which) */}
      <animated.div
        {...bind(i)}
        style={{
          transform: interpolate([rot, scale], trans),
          backgroundImage: `url(${cards[i]})`
        }}
      />
    </animated.div>
  ));
}

export default Deck;
```

And here, I am trying to split the CSS file into (two) styled components:
So it's basically more like a wrapper:

```
import React from "react";
import Tarot from "@components/SpringTarot";

import styled from "styled-components";

const Outer = styled.div`
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, avenir next, avenir,
    helvetica neue, helvetica, ubuntu, roboto, noto, segoe ui, arial, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: url("https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/b3e56831-8b98-4fee-b941-0e27f39883ab/Ad1_-cursor.png")
      16 16,
    auto;

  & > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    will-change: transform;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  & > div > div {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: auto 85%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 45vh;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 85vh;
    max-height: 570px;
    will-change: transform;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 12.5px 100px -10px rgba(50, 50, 73, 0.4),
      0 10px 10px -10px rgba(50, 50, 73, 0.3);
  }
`;

const SpringTarot = () => (
  <Outer>
    <Wrapper>
      <Tarot />
    </Wrapper>
  </Outer>
);

export default SpringTarot;
```

I have tried putting what's right now in the outer wrapper into the styled-component global styles, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to extend the native element you want to animate using animated. If you want to animate React components, styled-components, or elements on other platforms, then do this:

```
const AnimatedHeader = styled(animated.h1)`
  ...;
`
```

This is from [the official Spring docs](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics).